# Finding two strings for Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I'm watching [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#), want to send a message to an iPhone. I have a problem finding 
I'll provide code.
The first one I think it is `DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature` in access policies, am I right and the other one is my App name or what?

Here is the code

```
public const string ListenConnectionString = "<Azure DefaultListenSharedAccess Connection String>";
public const string NotificationHubName = "<Azure Notification Hub Name>";
```

Comment: i suppose you need to create azure notification hub and put its name in there and the key

Comment: I have created a azure notification hub but cant find the key.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/configure-notification-hub-portal-pns-settings ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-push-notifications-swift-apps-get-started#create-a-notification-hub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the document [create-a-namespace-and-a-notification-hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/create-notification-hub-portal#create-a-namespace-and-a-notification-hub), you can easily find the two keys:

1.`NotificationHubName`, in the step 4:

[image]

2.`ListenConnectionString`, in the step 6:

[image]